# Right Bitshift by 32 Returning Incorrect Values in Python 3.6.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

When shifting a variable 32 bits right, the variable itself is returned instead of the proper result (in this case zero). Additionally, anything over 32 returns the original shifted by 32-x bits. This is happening with a stored variable, but not when the integer itself is used in the command instead of the variable. I tried saving the object attribute to a local variable and performing the operation with the same strange results.
Any ideas?

```
board._current_player_board
Out[103]: 16777217
board._current_player_board >> 32
Out[104]: 16777217
16777217 >> 32
Out[105]: 0
board._current_player_board >> 31
Out[106]: 0
board._current_player_board >> 33
Out[107]: 8388608
16777217 >> 33
Out[108]: 0
16777217 >> 31
Out[109]: 0
board._current_player_board >> 34
Out[110]: 4194304
```

Comment: What type of variable is `_current_player_board`? I cannot reproduce this with regular integers. Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: This behavior is coherent with what the x86 rhs instruction does, and what typical C implementations of right shift do on such platform. Is `_current_player_board` some ctypes- or numpy-related low level type? Or are you running this on some atypical Python implementation (e.g. micropython)?

Comment: @MatteoItalia that helped a lot, thank you. ```_current_player_board``` was initially stored as an int, but converted when I used an ```|=``` command inside of a method and passed a numpy.int32 type attribute to it.

Comment: Dynamic typing strikes again. It's all fine as long as it quacks like a duck, until it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a strange edge case. The type of `board._current_player_board` *was* int, but it was being cast to numpy.int32 by an outside function call. The class definition that the board object used was in a file that didn't even import numpy!

There was a line `self._board |= self._board + (1 << 6 * move)` inside of a method of the board object here. A call was made to this method that was passing numpy.int32 type for move, which caused `self._board` to be cast down to the same type, thus the issues when shifting beyond 32 bits. Casting this value to int before passing it to that method prevented this issue.